# Python to Jython Gotchas?

Tags: python, migration, jython

I am starting migration process from python to jython. Has anyone done this with ease before?
What are the gotchas? Should I build first inside Jython IDE then deploy or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that in jython, while running under Java everything thing is 'Big-Endian' no matter what platform you're on, whereas on a PC/Linux/Mac(x86) platform python is Little Endian.   Make sure that when you're using struct.pack and struct.unpack you use the appropriate prefix

### without prefix

#### write data  (enessw.py)

```
import struct 
f = file('tmp.dat', 'wb') # binary 
f.write(struct.pack('IIII', 1,2,3,4)) # default endianess
```

#### read data (enessr.py)

```
import struct
f = file('tmp.dat', 'rb')
data = f.read()
ints = struct.unpack('IIII', data) # default endianess
print repr(ints)
```

#### Results

Write with python, read with jython

```
C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>python enessw.py

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>python enessr.py
(1, 2, 3, 4)

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>jython enessr.py
(16777216L, 33554432L, 50331648L, 67108864L)
```

Write with jython read with python

```
C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>jython enessw.py

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>jython enessr.py
(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>python enessr.py
(16777216, 33554432, 50331648, 67108864)
```

### The Fix

Use the < in the format string for pack and unpack.  This will instruct pack/unpack that the data is to be specifically little endian in format.

#### With '<IIII' as pack/unpack format

```
C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>python enessw.py

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>python enessr.py
(1, 2, 3, 4)

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>jython enessr.py
(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>jython enessw.py

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>jython enessr.py
(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>python enessw.py

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>python enessr.py
(1, 2, 3, 4)

C:\Documents and Settings\mat99856\My Documents\tmp>jython enessr.py
(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
```

### References

[struct.pack](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct.pack#struct.pack)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with that is Jython doesn't have any of the standard, or third-party, library modules that use C as it's implementation. Or have C compiled helper modules. There are quite a lot of those, and they may crop up in unexpected ways.

Also, Jython is much slower.

It really depends on what you are migrating, and how dependent it is on third-party modules and how much of "pure" Python it uses.

I would expect, however, a lot of problems with such a migration. Most Jython that I know if is written from scratch to do specific things with Java class, mainly for testing.